# error:duplicate class: a.b.c.R in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I'm facing an issue in android studio when i compile the project 
an error is throwing

**error:duplicate class: a.b.c.R**

i've included 5 third party libraries out of that one is included as library project

remaining 4 libraries included as dependency urls

Thx in adv.

***update***

Hi i added [build.gradle (app)](http://pastebin.com/4bXmV2DU)

Thx in adv.

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Hi @IntelliJ Amiya thanks for ur concern i've updated my question with my build.gradle

Comment: add this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`

Comment: sorry that too has no effect

Comment: comment `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`